# How to provide a ymal file to django-rest-swagger?

Tags: django, swagger

Using `django-rest-swagger` with `django-rest-framework` for documenting the API calls. I have written documentation of a view inside the view itself as a docstring in `YAML` syntax. 
I want to place all these docstrings from the views to a separate `YAML` file.
Is it possible to use the separate `YAML` file for the documentation ?